# Google Map - Angular 4 application failed to start project due to googlemaps library

Tags: angular

What I am using:

1. Angular 4.4.6
2. @types/googlemaps: 3.30.5

I have issue when try to start the project with red error message from command line:

`ERROR in D:/app/node_modules/@types/googlemaps/index.d.ts (3582,29): In ambient enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.`

I cannot upgrade Angular version and I GUEST he version issue or typescript version.

What really happening here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  Visual Studio, check the settings in your project Properties->TypeScript Build section and make sure TypeScript Version is set to "Use latest available" or at least something fairly recent. I suspect it's currently set to something prior to when TypeScript supported string enums.

Comment: I am using command line from window. my typescript version is `3.5.3`. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Can you try and change your typescript version to 2.4. That might solve your issue.